# python: iteration over non sequence error

Tags: python, iteration

Just starting problem 164 for project euler, and i want a function to output a list of the sum of each set of 3 consecutive digits in a 20 digit number. Here is my function.

```
    def func(n):
    sumlist = []
    m = str(n)
    for i in range(0,18):
         sumlist.append(sum(int(m[i])+int(m[i+1])+int(m[i+2])))
    return sumlist
```

I keep getting the iteration over non sequence error and i can't figure out why i should. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

**EDIT**

The full traceback is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "peproblem164.py", line 8, in ? print func(11201201201201201201) 
  File "peproblem164.py", line 5, in func    
    sumlist.append(sum(int(m[i])+int(m[i+1])+int(m[i+2]))) 
TypeError: iteration over non-sequence'
```

Comment: post the full traceback please...

Comment: sorry the full traceback is:

'Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "peproblem164.py", line 8, in ?
    print func(11201201201201201201)
  File "peproblem164.py", line 5, in func
    sumlist.append(sum(int(m[i])+int(m[i+1])+int(m[i+2])))
TypeError: iteration over non-sequence'

Comment: @DomWigmore: Welcome to StackOverflow. In the future, it would be most helpful to include *all* relevant information in your question. In addition, you should include any requested information in the body of your question, not as a comment. That way, potential answerers can see all of the relevant information at a glance. Anyway see my edit, I added a few more pointers.

Answer (score 3):

That's because

```
int(m[i]) + int(m[i+1]) + int(m[i+2])
```

isn't a sequence. It's an `int`. I believe you mean:

```
sumlist.append(sum((int(m[i]), int(m[i+1]), int(m[i+2]))
```

this will work because

```
(int(m[i]), int(m[i+1]), int(m[i+2]))
```

*is* a sequence.

All in all, it would be easier to work with a list of integers, rather than a string, so it would make sense to convert `m` into `int`s first:

```
m = map(int, str(n))
```

and then use Python's slicing syntax to get the subsequence sums:

```
for i in range(18): #Leaving out the start argument is equivalent to range(0, 18)
    sumlist.append(sum(m[i:i+3]))
```

and it would be even more pythonic to use a *list comprehension* instead (not to mention *faster*):

```
sumlist = [m[i:i+3] for i in range(18)] #same thing as the for loop
```

Comment: Ah yeah, thanks a lot, now i see it that a pretty stupid error to make. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You really don't need the sum call.  Replace

```
sumlist.append(sum(int(m[i])+int(m[i+1])+int(m[i+2])))
```

with

```
sumlist.append(int(m[i])+int(m[i+1])+int(m[i+2]))
```